# Add a backslash to all non-word characters in a string

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, str-replace

Since I want to make each element of string in a list (`url_key`) as a regex to identify whether an element in another list has a pattern, I need to add a backslash to all non-word characters for every element in `url_key` using python.

Example of my code:

```
import re
sentences = ["Disallow DCCP sockets due to such NFC-3456",
            "Check at http://www.n.io/search?query=title++sub/file.html",
            "Specifies the hash algorithm on them"]

url_key = ['www.n.io/search?query=title++sub', 'someweb.org/dirs.io']    # there are thousands of elements
add_key = ['NFC-[0-9]{4}', 'CEZ-[0-9a-z]{4,8}']    # there are hundreds of elements

pattern = url_key + add_key
mykey = re.compile('(?:% s)' % '|'.join(pattern))

for item in sentences:
    if mykey.search(item):
        print (item, ' --> Keyword is found')
    else:
        print (item, ' --> Keyword is not Found')
```

But this code gives me an error:

```
error                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-80-5348ee9c65ec> in <module>()
      8 
      9 pattern = url_key + add_key
---> 10 mykey = re.compile('(?:% s)' % '|'.join(pattern))
     11 
     12 for item in sentences:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/re.py in compile(pattern, flags)
    231 def compile(pattern, flags=0):
    232     "Compile a regular expression pattern, returning a pattern object."
--> 233     return _compile(pattern, flags)
    234 
    235 def purge():

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/re.py in _compile(pattern, flags)
    299     if not sre_compile.isstring(pattern):
    300         raise TypeError("first argument must be string or compiled pattern")
--> 301     p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
    302     if not (flags & DEBUG):
    303         if len(_cache) >= _MAXCACHE:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/sre_compile.py in compile(p, flags)
    560     if isstring(p):
    561         pattern = p
--> 562         p = sre_parse.parse(p, flags)
    563     else:
    564         pattern = None

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/sre_parse.py in parse(str, flags, pattern)
    853 
    854     try:
--> 855         p = _parse_sub(source, pattern, flags & SRE_FLAG_VERBOSE, 0)
    856     except Verbose:
    857         # the VERBOSE flag was switched on inside the pattern.  to be

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/sre_parse.py in _parse_sub(source, state, verbose, nested)
    414     while True:
    415         itemsappend(_parse(source, state, verbose, nested + 1,
--> 416                            not nested and not items))
    417         if not sourcematch("|"):
    418             break

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/sre_parse.py in _parse(source, state, verbose, nested, first)
    763                 sub_verbose = ((verbose or (add_flags & SRE_FLAG_VERBOSE)) and
    764                                not (del_flags & SRE_FLAG_VERBOSE))
--> 765                 p = _parse_sub(source, state, sub_verbose, nested + 1)
    766             if not source.match(")"):
    767                 raise source.error("missing ), unterminated subpattern",

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/sre_parse.py in _parse_sub(source, state, verbose, nested)
    414     while True:
    415         itemsappend(_parse(source, state, verbose, nested + 1,
--> 416                            not nested and not items))
    417         if not sourcematch("|"):
    418             break

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/sre_parse.py in _parse(source, state, verbose, nested, first)
    617             if item[0][0] in _REPEATCODES:
    618                 raise source.error("multiple repeat",
--> 619                                    source.tell() - here + len(this))
    620             if sourcematch("?"):
    621                 subpattern[-1] = (MIN_REPEAT, (min, max, item))

error: multiple repeat at position 31
```

Expected result:

```
Disallow DCCP sockets due to such NFC-3456 --> Keyword is found 
Check at http://www.n.io/search?query=title++sub/file.html --> Keyword is found
Specifies the hash algorithm on them --> Keyword is not found
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain why you need to do this? This sounds like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/322040) you're trying to hack by hand, when an existing string escaping API would do the trick (without necessarily behaving exactly the way you describe). Also, saying "didn't work" isn't very helpful; a [MCVE] should show the observed output (including traceback if an exception was raised).

Comment: I agree with @ShadowRanger entirely. Be careful, take your time, don’t just jump on something because “it works”.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem is that string escapes are taking effect before the regex substitution escapes. Switching to raw strings (to inhibit string escapes) and escaping your backslash (because `\\` is itself a substitution escape) will fix this:

```
>>> print(re.sub(r'(\W)', r'\\\1', '?:n.io/search?query=title++sub'))
\?\:n\.io\/search\?query\=title\+\+sub
```

Note that you may not need such extensive escaping. If you just want to escape regex special characters, `re.escape` will do this for you:

```
>>> print(re.escape('?:n.io/search?query=title++sub'))
\?:n\.io/search\?query=title\+\+sub
```

without adding unnecessary escapes (ones that aren't needed to despecialize regex characters).

Comment: what if I want to save that result into a list, instead of just printing? E.g. `lst = ['\?:n\.io\/search\?query=title\+\+sub']`

Comment: @YusufUMS: Just wrap it in square brackets instead of `print()`? `[re.escape('?:n.io/search?query=title++sub')]`

Comment: @YusufUMS Do you know how to create a list?

Answer (score 1):

You should either use raw strings:

```
result = re.sub('(\W)', r'\\\1', mystring)
```

or escape backslashes too:

```
result = re.sub('(\W)', '\\\\\\1', mystring)
```